# Using box-sizing: border-box; on solid and outline buttons

Tags: css

Two buttons next to each other, one solid and one with a border. Now shouldn't box-sizing: border-box; means that they are both the same height (and width)... Or what am I missing?

Example:

```css
.btn{
 padding: 1rem 2rem;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 5px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn-primary{
 background: red;
}

.btn-outline{
 border: 5px solid red;
        position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary">Test Me</a>
<a class="btn btn-outline">Test Me</a>
```

Comment: box-sizing has no effect if you don't specify width/height

Comment: You are missing that box-sizing specifies how the overall width/height of an element are calculated, based on the _given_ width/height, borders and padding – but you have not specified a width or height here.

Comment: *border-box tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height* --> notice the *you specify* (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: Thanks everyone, it seems a transparent border of the same width added to all buttons is the way to go.